# powerbook g4, dead screen and beeps

Tags: screen, powerpc

I've a powerbook g4, it should be the "PowerBook G4 (Gigabit Ethernet)" [named here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3065). It was on the table where I work to gather dust.

The screen is dead, but I clearly listen the boot up sound follower by a noise and 3 beeps. I've tried to connect the computer though the DVI port without success, the screen doesn't show anything. Is there any hope to get it working?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three beeps is an indication that for some reason it's not been able to successfully pass the RAM check part of the POST, or a bit more seriously that the logic board is dead. First step is to open it up, pull the RAM and boot it, if it makes one beep then it's the RAM so reseat it and see if it works. If it makes three beeps again, then it's a new logic board.

Comment: nice, it makes one beep after I removed the ram. I'll replace it! thanks

Comment: Obviously, try reseating the RAM and trying it again. Sometimes that's all it takes.

Comment: Yeah do the reseat thing first, and if there's two sticks try just one, might save yourself a couple of quid!